# Having trouble with the Dim and Set command in VBA, compile error "mismatch"

Tags: vba, excel

Writing a short script in VBA to sort through data, essentially counting the number of names entered into a list, and printing them into a new column. However, the & in the row "Set Staff 1" is causing a compile error due to a mismatch. It seems to be caused by setting two ranges at the same time. I get the impression that there's a straightforward solution...

```
Sub Staffing()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim Staff1 As Range
Dim Staff2 As Range
Dim Staff3 As Range
Dim Staff4 As Range
Dim Staff5 As Range
Dim Staff6 As Range
Dim Staff7 As Range

While i <= 300
Set Rng = Range("J" & i)
Set Staff1 = ("X" & i)
Set Staff2 = ("AD" & i)
Set Staff3 = ("AJ" & i)
Set Staff4 = ("AP" & i)
Set Staff5 = ("BB" & i)
Set Staff6 = ("BH" & i)
Set Staff7 = ("BN" & i)

If Staff1 <> "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
i = i + 1
If Staff2 <> "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
i = i + 1
If Staff3 <> "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
i = i + 1
If Staff4 <> "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
i = i + 1
If Staff5 <> "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
i = i + 1
If Staff6 <> "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
i = i + 1
If Staff7 <> "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
i = i + 1

Else
Stop
End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Thanks for everyone's patience. I had mad HUGE errors in writing this first code, but have fixed them thanks to your help and some of my own trial and error. The correct code is as follows. I'm sure now you'll be able to see what I was trying to do!

```
Sub StaffingNumbers()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim Staff1 As Range
Dim Staff2 As Range
Dim Staff3 As Range
Dim Staff4 As Range
Dim Staff5 As Range
Dim Staff6 As Range
Dim Staff7 As Range
Dim Staff8 As Range
Dim Staff9 As Range
Dim Staff10 As Range

i = 3

While i <= 300
Set Rng = Range("J" & i)
Set Staff1 = Range("X" & i)
Set Staff2 = Range("AD" & i)
Set Staff3 = Range("AJ" & i)
Set Staff4 = Range("AP" & i)
Set Staff5 = Range("AV" & i)
Set Staff6 = Range("BB" & i)
Set Staff7 = Range("BH" & i)
Set Staff8 = Range("BN" & i)

If Staff1 = "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
i = i + 1
ElseIf Staff1 <> "" And Staff2 = "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
i = i + 1
ElseIf Staff2 <> "" And Staff3 = "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
i = i + 1
ElseIf Staff3 <> "" And Staff4 = "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
i = i + 1
ElseIf Staff4 <> "" And Staff5 = "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
i = i + 1
ElseIf Staff5 <> "" And Staff6 = "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
i = i + 1
ElseIf Staff6 <> "" And Staff7 = "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
i = i + 1
ElseIf Staff7 <> "" And Staff8 = "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "7"
i = i + 1
ElseIf Staff8 <> "" Then
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "8"
i = i + 1


Else
Stop
End If
Wend

Set Rng = Nothing
Set Staff1 = Nothing
Set Staff2 = Nothing
Set Staff3 = Nothing
Set Staff4 = Nothing
Set Staff5 = Nothing
Set Staff6 = Nothing
Set Staff7 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The way you set the first rng should be a clue. `Set Staff1 = Range("X" & i)`

Comment: Ah, knew it was something silly like that. Thanks!

Comment: It also isn't clear what you want to do. Should there be a bunch of `ElseIf`instead of `If` alfter the first `If`?

Comment: Yeah, there should and I fixed it there. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `Range` in that line, first line with set `Set Rng = Range("J" & i)` is correct, all the others should be similar too.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `Range` in `Set Staff2 = Range("AD" & i)` which should be `Set Staff2 = Range("AD" & i)`

Also, don't forget to free your objects at the end of the proc, by using `Set Staff2 = Nothing`

You also forgot to close most of your `If` statements with `End If`, I let it as it was because I don't know what you want to do with your code :

```
Sub Staffing()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim Staff1 As Range
Dim Staff2 As Range
Dim Staff3 As Range
Dim Staff4 As Range
Dim Staff5 As Range
Dim Staff6 As Range
Dim Staff7 As Range

i = 1
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere")

While i <= 300
    With Ws
        Set Rng = .Range("J" & i)
        Set Staff1 = .Range("X" & i)
        Set Staff2 = .Range("AD" & i)
        Set Staff3 = .Range("AJ" & i)
        Set Staff4 = .Range("AP" & i)
        Set Staff5 = .Range("BB" & i)
        Set Staff6 = .Range("BH" & i)
        Set Staff7 = .Range("BN" & i)
    End With

    If Staff1.Value <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
        i = i + 1
        If Staff2 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
        i = i + 1
        If Staff3 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
        i = i + 1
        If Staff4 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
        i = i + 1
        If Staff5 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
        i = i + 1
        If Staff6 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
        i = i + 1
        If Staff7 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
        i = i + 1

    Else
        Stop
    End If
Wend

    Set Ws = Nothing
    Set Rng = Nothing
    Set Staff1 = Nothing
    Set Staff2 = Nothing
    Set Staff3 = Nothing
    Set Staff4 = Nothing
    Set Staff5 = Nothing
    Set Staff6 = Nothing
    Set Staff7 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added your suggestions. However, now I am getting a runtime error 1004 of method 'range' of object'_global'. Is this just a matter of defining what the Active Sheet should be somewhere?

Comment: On which line? Indeed referencing the sheet would be a great idea anyway! ;) Maybe you should set i=0 before looping, look amended code! ;)

Comment: The line is Set Rng = Range("J" & i). How exactly do I reference the sheet? Thanks!

Comment: Correction done, it was not i=0 but i=1 to initialize and I added the line to reference easily the sheet by name, give it a try after changing the name of the sheet! ;)

Comment: Thanks. I actually fixed the code completely now (see edit), without the reference line. I'll keep your advice in mind in future though!

Answer (score 1):

The logic of what you want to accomplish after the range assignments is not clear. Perhaps this is what you hope to chieve.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim Staff1 As Range, Staff2 As Range, Staff3 As Range
Dim Staff4 As Range, Staff5 As Range, Staff6 As Range
Dim Staff7 As Range, Rng As Range

While i <= 300
    Set Rng = Range("J" & i)
    Set Staff1 = Range("X" & i)
    Set Staff2 = Range("AD" & i)
    Set Staff3 = Range("AJ" & i)
    Set Staff4 = Range("AP" & i)
    Set Staff5 = Range("BB" & i)
    Set Staff6 = Range("BH" & i)
    Set Staff7 = v("BN" & i)

    If Staff1 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Staff2 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Staff3 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Staff4 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Staff5 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Staff6 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf Staff7 <> "" Then
        Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Stop
    End If
Wend
```

It really isn't clear why the [Stop statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6acc062s.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is there. Perhaps you want to exit the Do While? That would be `Exit Do`.

Comment: I've found a solution myself thanks to your help, and some of my own trial and error. I had made large mistakes in the initial code. See my edit for the complete script.